# Sort SQLite database by date only in android

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a SQlite database with date stored as string datatype (dd-mm-yyyy format). How can I sort the rows in my database by date ?

Comment: use `ORDER by date ASC`

Comment: `ASC` is the default, so it's completely optional. To sort the other direction, use `DESC`

Comment: your data format is basically wrong (its batter to use primitive datatime format like `Integer number of seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The Query for sorting date is:**

```
SELECT EventDate,Event,ID from EventCalenderTable Order By EventDate ASC
```

**Note:**
SQLite only knows three [date formats](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html):

- Text ISO8601 strings ("YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.SSS")
- Real Julian day numbers since November 24, 4714 B.C
- Integer number of seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC

SQLite does have [five date/time functions](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) for converting between formats.

Comment: `ASC` is the default, so it's completely optional. To sort the other direction, use `DESC`

Comment: My date column is varchar type, so does this query work with the same

Comment: It should work. But I didn't try. So have a try and share your result here, so that next warrior could survive following your footsteps.